# How do I make a pattern based replacement in sympy which recognises factors of any form?

Tags: sympy, substitution, symbolic-math

I want sympy to replace, any time it sees an expression of the form

factor1 * exp^{ - factor2 * x^2}

with an expression expr1.

Here, I want sympy to recognise the pattern everytime factor1 and factor 2 does not contain the symbol x.

The problem is, only if I know the exact form of factor1 and factor2 am I able to make the replacement work as of now.

How can I do it generally?

For example, in the following code, i am getting the expected output of -b + c

```
import sympy as sp
a, b, c, q = sp.symbols('a b c q')
f= (a)*sp.exp(c *q) - b

y = sp.Wild('y', properties=[lambda x: isinstance(x, sp.Symbol)])

x = sp.Wild('x', properties=[lambda x: isinstance(x, sp.Symbol)])

f.replace(x*sp.exp(y * q), c)
```

But, in the following slightly modified code, replacement is not working

```
import sympy as sp
a, b, c, q = sp.symbols('a b c q')
f= (a/b)*sp.exp(c *q) - b

y = sp.Wild('y', properties=[lambda x: isinstance(x, sp.Symbol)])

x = sp.Wild('x', properties=[lambda x: isinstance(x, sp.Symbol)])

ans = f.replace(x*sp.exp(y * q), c)

print(ans)
```

Output: a*exp(c*q)/b - b

Answer (score 2):

The `match` attempts to match a whole expression or subexpression. You told your Wild symbols to only match a symbol. The node search does not break a product up into all possible subsets of products so `a/b*exp(c*q)` does not match. I usually give up after several attempts of tuning a `Wild` to make it work and just define what I am looking for explicitly:

```py
def hit(e,q):
    if not e.is_Mul: return False
    i, ex = e.as_independent(q)
    if not isinstance(ex, exp): return False
    i, d = ex.args[0].as_independent(q,as_Add=False)
    if d == q: # or however you want to match
        return True
```

You said you were interested in `x**2` expressions in the `exp` but used `q` in you example. So I used a parameter `q` that can be specified.

```py
>>> from sympy.abc import *
>>> from sympy import *
# your code
>>> f.replace(lambda x:hit(x,q), lambda x:y)
-b + y
>>> ((a/b)*exp(c/d*x**2)+e).replace(lambda i: hit(i,x**2), lambda i: A)
A + e
```

`